# Why can't I add comment and even can't delete my own answer?

Tags: discussion, bug

It works fine before until this afternoon.

I can't add any comment at any answer on stack-overflow.

And even can't delete my own answer(I find out I answer wrong).

It's so weird and haven't encounter before.

There is only one way I could do comment and delete my own post is using `Incognito mode`, it could work normally.

But it's so tired I have to log in every times if closed the page.

Is there any suggestion?

Thanks a lot.

PS: click add comment and delete answer will scroll to top of the page..

My Web Browser:
Chrome: 83.0.4103.116 (64 Bit)

**Update**

I have try log out all device and re-login many times.(not work)

Comment: On what site(s)? When you try to add comment or delete answer, what happens? You see error message? Anything in developer console?

Comment: Also, what is your OS?

Comment: On `stack-overflow`, it works perfect at `stackExchange` but not on `stack-overflow`, there is no any error message just click it and it scroll to the top....again and again.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask Win10, it works perfect before. It happened in afternoon until now.

Comment: Well, first thing I'd check is userscripts - disable them all and try again. Including ad blockers. They might be messing around with the JS required to perform those actions, or the HTML around it. (e.g. ad blocker might remove a required element from the page when it has "suspicious" class.)

Comment: Oh~ It worked when I close the `Recat Developer Tools` ,Thanks a lot, I have to observe for period of time. Would you mind to add your comment as an answer again let me accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> click add comment and delete answer will scroll to top of the page.

When such thing happens, with no obvious errors in the console/network tab of dev console, it usually means a userscript that you have installed in your browser is causing the problem.

Userscripts can do the following:

- Interfere with JS code
- Hide elements in the page or remove them from the DOM

Any of those can easily break the code required to perform actions like posting comments, deleting posts, and much more.

So to verify that's the case, disable **all** userscripts, including ad blocker of all kinds, and try again. If it works, you can enable the userscripts one by one, until you find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks again, it just break out suddenly. It's so hard to find out the question.

Comment: @高鵬翔 yeah, probably due to change in SO code (HTML) or something like that.